# drop down menu going behind iframe containing pdf

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am having trouble getting my drop down navigation menu infront of iframe in IE. My drop down menu is going behind the iframe where I am loading pdf. I tried z-index, wmode, alpha transparency but none of that worked. Is it possible to get drop down menu infront of iframe containing pdf?

Comment: Is the drop down a <ul> ? Does this happen in all browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

drop-downs are major pains in IE- esp in IE6 and with flash.  You might need to absolutely place the elements on the page.  The ones you specify first will appear above the others.

Comment: well thanks. I gave position absolute to iframe which sloved the issue for drop down.